# How can i get the symbol for the flash used in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I want to be able to get the name of the symbol that was used in a flash message.

For example: I am looking for a function or helper that would return the "warning" when flash[:warning] is active.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: flash.keys will give you all the entries in the flash.  Its basically just as special hash.

Comment: That seems to return [:warning] with the brackets and semicolon. Do you know a helper that will pull that out? Otherwise, I guess i'm going for regex :/

Comment: @Jakcst: That's an array with a single symbol inside. It would be more helpful if you would give more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to get the string value 'warning' extracted from my flash[:warning]... or 'notice' from flash[:notice]... I seemed to get a solid result with the following ... flash.keys.first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me. I wanted the string value 'warning' extracted from flash[:warning]

```
flash.keys.first
```